# 4-net in binary hypercube

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a binary hypercube $\mathbb{F}_2^n$. What is the largest size of a subset $S$ such that $d(x,y)\geq 4$ for all $x,y\in S$ ($x\neq y$), where $d(x,y)$ is the Hamming distance between $x$ and $y$ (number of non-zero entries in $x-y$)?

It is obviously bounded from above by $2^n/n$ because the $1$-balls of each element in $S$ are disjoint. Any better bound?

Comment: There are nice bounds coming from coding theory. Look for extended Hamming codes, you can start [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#Hamming_codes_with_additional_parity_.28SECDED.29).